# How can I solve the 2D diffusion equation over a region that contains mobile sinks?

Tags: differential-equations, regions, finite-element-method, simulation

I am looking for guidance on how to simulate the following system in 2D.

I have a region, assumed to be rectangular for simplicity. A substance is diffusing into this region from its boundary. Again for simplicity, we assume a constant input from one side of the boundary. Let's think of it as a shallow, rectangular water tank with a semipermeable membrane along one side, through which a substance enters the tank at a constant rate.

Now comes the tricky part. Inside the region are small mobile sinks for the diffusing substance. Assume that they are circular and uniformly absorbent around their circumferences. Think of them as motile cells that absorb the diffusing substance and also swim around in response to its concentration gradient. We can assume that the fluid is incompressible and nonviscous. My goal is to study how the sink (position) dynamics and diffusion dynamics interact.

Mathematica seems to be able to handle PDEs on regions with curved boundaries, using FEMs. So, solving the diffusion equation on a rectangular region with a circular hole in it is no problem. But how can I make the position of the hole time-dependent and solve for this time dependence simultaneously with the diffusion dynamics?

Comment: Have you solved the problem with the trajectories of the mobile sinks specified in advance?  If not, that might be a good place to begin.

Comment: First of all, you should write down (maybe, derive) the equations describing the system. These must include both the diffusion equations with the boundary conditions and those for the motion of sinks. In parallel, please check Menu/Help/WolframDocumentation/NDSolve/Scope/PartialDifferentialEquations where you will find examples of solutions of the diffusion equation. After that, please explain to us what does not work in your case? Where is the problem?